Preserving original shape in stroke to path
I'd like to produce an outline of a leaf shape to make a cookie cutter. I would like a thin section (cutter) and a thick section (handle) and I'm going to make the 3D shape starting with an SVG I create in Inkscape.
In Inkscape, I've outlined the leaf using the pen tool, duplicated it, and made 2 strokes: the green one is very thin (0.4mm wide) and the black one is very thick (3mm wide).

If I highlight the green stroke and hit "Path > Stroke to Path" then it becomes a convincing looking outline, like this:

Unfortunately if I select the wide outline and hit "Path > Stroke to Path" it mangles the outline badly and leaves me with a curve I can't extrude in my other software, like this:

How can I do Stroke to Path on this wide stroke and preserve the original curvature of the line?
I've seen some posts online about similar issues when the scale is too small, and this question for instance recommends to scale it up before the Stroke to Path, but in my case it looks the same either way.

I'd like to suggest a different method.

Draw your green line, and do Path > Stroke to Path.

Duplicate this, send to the back, apply an Offset live path effect

Move the offset control to thicken up the line, and change the fill to black.

In the LPE panel, flatten the effect.


An example of the result

